# How do I fix error: expected ')' for an 'if' statement?

Tags: c

I was trying to write a code in C to check if a number is odd without using the modulus operator but I kept running into this error when trying to compile:

**20: error: expected ')'**

(I denoted line 20 in the code block through a comment. It's after the 'else')

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* check if number is odd or even */

/* something like n = 1111 1110 | x
 * results in n = 1111 1111 if last bit of x is 1
 * hence, if ~n = 0 then number is odd */
int truth;

int main()
{
    void oddoreven(int 3);

    if (truth)
        printf("even");
    else //this is line 20. 
        printf("odd");

    return 0;
}

void oddoreven(int p)
{
    truth = -126 | p;
    truth = ~truth;
}
```

Comment: The answers have shown how to remove the _syntax errors_. But do note that there are _logical errors_ in your program. (It says `3` is even)

Comment: was finally able to compile with the answers, thank you everyone! I'll have to give the checkmark to the first answer since all would have worked for me. Yeah, there are logical errors that I have to fix. I have some reading up to do. Thanks again to all!

Comment: @PalLaden I just reopened this page by chance and saw your answer with a solution to my logic problem which is far more elegant than the one I made after the syntax fix. I must award the check to you instead. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a working program with fixed logic and syntax.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

/* check if number is odd or even */

/**
 * returns 1 if number is odd, 0 otherwise
 */
int oddOrEven(int p)
{
    return (1 & p);
}

int main()
{
    
    if (oddOrEven(3))
        printf("Odd");
    else
        printf("Even");

    return 0;
}
```

### Syntax changes:

- Function `oddOrEven()` moved before `main()`. You can also write the function prototype and keep the definition at the original position.
- Changed `void oddoreven(int 3);` to `oddOrEven(3)`. This is the proper syntax for a function call.

### Logic explained:

You wrote

> something like n = 1111 1110 | x results in n = 1111 1111 if last bit of x is 1 hence, if ~n = 0 then number is odd

However,
it depends on the size of your integer type.
`n = 1111 1110 | x` results in `n = 0011 1111 1111` if `x` is `0011 1100 1111`.
For `n = 1111 1111`, `~n = 0` only if the size of `n` is 8 bits.

In binary, the number `1` means a certain number of zeros with 1 at the end.
`&` is the bitwise and operator.
Hence,
`1 & n` will result in 1 if and only if the last bit of x is 1.

Answer (score 2):

I don't get the error you mention.
I get errors for the line

`void oddoreven(int 3);`

where you are mixing protype and call of the function.

You can fix by defining and calling the function correctly.

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* check if number is odd or even */

/* something like n = 1111 1110 | x
 * results in n = 1111 1111 if last bit of x is 1
 * hence, if ~n = 0 then number is odd */
int truth;


void oddoreven(int p)
{
    truth = -126 | p;
    truth = ~truth;
}
int main(void)
{
    oddoreven(3);

    if (truth)
        printf("even");
    else //this is line 20. 
        printf("odd");

    return 0;
}
```

I.e. do the definition of the function before main, which saves you doing the protype explicitly.
Inside main call the function instead of declaring it. I.e. use the 3 as parameter, wihtout type and drop the return type. That makes it a call.

Answer (score 2):

You have multiple errors first one is you can't call a function like that it should be `oddoreven(3);` where 3 is already an integer you don't need the data type.

Next one is you have to declare the function above the function if you are going to write it below the main function or you can directly write it above the main function.

Your logic also seems wrong use something like this

```
#include <stdio.h>



int oddoreven(int p)
{
    if ( p & 1 == 1 )
      return 0;
   else
      return 1;
    
}

int main()
{

    if (oddoreven(4))
        printf("even");
    else //this is line 20. 
        printf("odd");

    return 0;
}
```

and changes for your code

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* check if number is odd or even */

/* something like n = 1111 1110 | x
 * results in n = 1111 1111 if last bit of x is 1
 * hence, if ~n = 0 then number is odd */
int truth;
void oddoreven(int p)
{
    truth = -126 | p;
    truth = ~truth;
}

int main()
{
    oddoreven(3);

    if (truth)
        printf("even");
    else //this is line 20. 
        printf("odd");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change `void oddorevern(int 3)` in `main` to `oddoreven(3)`. When calling a function, you don't need to attach `void`. Also, in C you need to declare a function before calling it.

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* check if number is odd or even */

/* something like n = 1111 1110 | x
 * results in n = 1111 1111 if last bit of x is 1
 * hence, if ~n = 0 then number is odd */
int truth;

void oddoreven(int p)
{
    truth = -126 | p;
    truth = ~truth;
}

int main()
{
    oddoreven(3);

    if (truth)
        printf("even");
    else //this is line 20. 
        printf("odd");

    return 0;
}
```

like this

Answer (score 1):

In your code

```
 void oddoreven(int 3);
```

is a function declaration syntax, and you can only use the arguments as the type and the variable. So, the

- correct syntax would be

  ```
    void oddoreven(int);
  ```
- correct place would be outside and before `main()`.

If you wanted to make a function call, you have to do it like

```
oddoreven(3);
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly the function definition of oddoreven() should be written before calling the function. Even if you are writing the definition of function oddoreven() like you have written, then you must write the function prototype before calling the function. In this way the compiler is aware of the function definition.

Also, the syntax for calling the function oddoreven() is also wrong.

Change  `void oddoreven(int 3);` to `oddoreven((int)3);` or `oddoreven(3);`.

Full Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int truth;

void oddoreven(int p)
{
    truth = -126 | p;
    truth = ~truth;
}
int main()
{
    oddoreven((int)3);

    if (truth)
        printf("even");
    else //this is line 20. 
        printf("odd");
    return 0;
}
```